# Magento 2 - how to load JS template from filesystem in jquery widget

Tags: magento2

For example, native Magento theme-frontend-blank\web\js\navigation-menu.js has such code:

```
$.widget('mage.navigationMenu', {
    options: {
    ...
        collapsableDropdownTemplate:
            '<script type="text/x-magento-template">' +
                '<li class="level0 level-top more parent">' +
                    '<div class="submenu">' +
                        '<ul><%= elems %></ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</script>'
```

And then they do

```
        this.collapsableDropdown = $(
            mageTemplate(
                this.options.collapsableDropdownTemplate,
                {elems: this.elemsToCollapseClone}
            )
        );
```

**Is it possible to do something like this**

**collapsableDropdownTemplate: getTemplate(some_relative_path_to_template) ?** 
instead of

```
        collapsableDropdownTemplate:
            '<script type="text/x-magento-template">' +
                '<li class="level0 level-top more parent">' +
                    '<div class="submenu">' +
                        '<ul><%= elems %></ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</li>' +
            '</script>'
```

My template is a little bit bigger and I want to allow frontend developers to modify it.

Comment: You mean just for the local development?

Comment: why local? path_in_filesystem is incorrect term, I mean some relative path to template

Comment: I am not 100% clear on the terms here. Can you please explain with an example?

Comment: I just want to remove plain HTML from JS code. As you can see, collapsableDropdownTemplate: has <script type="text/x-magento-template"> and plain HTML. I want to move HTML somewhere.

Comment: If you haven't already, consider posting this to the Magento SE as well.